# How aerospike handle creation of same record by multiple connections?

Tags: aerospike

If two connections are trying to create the same record, how will aerospike ensure that only one of them will be able to execute successfully? 
Aerospike maintains a queue for the operations on a single record. So if a record exists all the operations on that record can execute serially.
But what will happen if there is a create operation being called by multiple connections?

Comment: It's an upsert by default, but you can control that in the policy for the write operation. Every language client supports it, so which client are you using?

Comment: @RonenBotzer I was basically interested in the details of its implementation. pg gupta answer has explained that. BTW I am using JAVA client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, since Aerospike serializes transactions, if the create only client policy is used (for example, in java, the [recordExistsAction](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/WritePolicy.html#recordExistsAction)), the second one will fail, but by default, the second "create" would be treated as an update...

Comment: Is there any documentation where can I read the implementation of record queue? I want to know how it is created and managed. And initially, if there is no record the queue also is not there. What will happen if two connections are parallelly calling the create operation of a record? When will the queue be created and these two connections will be put in it?

Answer (score 4):

The queue where the transaction will get parked is the Transaction Pending List in the rwHash.  Attached is a flow chart of how a create (not update) transaction flows through in server version prior to 4.7 release. [image: Create Transaction]

rwHash Data Structure:

[image: rwHash Data Structure]